# Image picker scanned to null

Tags: flutter, dart, imagepicker

```
File _image;
    final picker = ImagePicker();

    Future getImage() async {
      final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

      setState(() {
        if (pickedFile != null) {
          _image = File(pickedFile.path);
        } else {
          print('No image selected.');
        }
      });
    }
```

output :

> D/MediaScannerConnection(16161): Scanned
> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxxx.xxxx/files/Pictures/9d9ed6a1-292c-428a-bf24-38ea1a58742c6940060118053310767.jpg
> to null

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred to me too. I have found that somehow the captured image data is lost due to the `MainActivity` is killed after the `image_picker` finishes. To solve this, just add retrieve lost data handler. You can find the example code on the documentation [here](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker). (Refer section: Handling `MainActivity` destruction on Android #)